# Cache a dynamically generated image

Tags: php, browser-cache

I am generating some images using a PHP script.
I want to cache the images, so the browser doesn't have to load them each time.
I have added these headers:

```
'max-age' => 3600
'Etag' => md5($image->getSlug())
'last-modified' => $image->getUpdatedAt()
'Vary' => 'Accept-Encoding'
'content-length' => (size of the image)
'Content-type' => 'image/jpeg'
```

but the image is not cached, and it is loaded every time by the browser.

The response headers look like these (using Firebug):

```
Date             Sun, 04 Sep 2011 00:25:45 GMT
Server           Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
X-Powered-By     PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze1
Cache-Control    max-age=3600, private
Etag            "9280c6c672c6535c13b7481972f9ac39"
Last-Modified    Sat, 27 Aug 2011 01:36:24 GMT
Vary             Accept-Encoding
Content-Length   26231
Connection       close
Content-Type     image/jpeg
```

Does anyone have any idea what is wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

One way you can force an image to be cached is to set the `Last-Modified` tag to the date and time that the image you want to use was created. For example:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0); //disable error reporting as it will corrupt the image
session_start(); //start a php session
$date = date(DATE_RFC822);
//some code to connect to a mysql database
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM images WHERE sessionid='$sessionid'");
if ($query and mysqli_num_rows($query) == 1) { //if mysql returned one row
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query); //get the row as an array
    $date = $row["date"]; //set the date to the one in the database
} else { //if the user has never seen the image before
    mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO images SET sessionid='$sessionid', date='$date'"); //put the session id and date into the database for later use
}
header("Last-Modified: $date");
//some code that would generate and send the image
```

Don't forget to create a database (in any database program) that contains a table called `images` with `sessionid`, which should be the primary key, and `date`. Both should be strings.

Comment: If you look at my original post, you will see I have included Last-modified.

Comment: @Ako Ah, yes, sorry, my bad. Well, I can't think of anything else that can be done, except for possibly saving the contents of the images using “file_put_contents” and then using the image file name on the page that shows it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate and add an Expires: header. For example:

```
Expires: Fri, 30 Oct 2011 14:19:41 GMT
```